# Text of anchor tag does not change using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I execute an ajax function that takes 3 seconds + so in this time I would like the text of the a link **(code below, and 1 in image)** to change to "Please wait...". I tried the JavaScript code below but what happens is the text does not change and the function executes as normal. Please if someone could point out my mistake.

**HTML :**

```
<a id="emailGarageList" href="javascript:EmailGarageList(347)">Email Garage List...</a>
```

**Screenshot :**

[image]

**Javascript :**

```
function EmailGarageList(fId) {
    $('#emailGarageList').text('Please wait...');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/EmailGarageList",
        data: "{'fId':" + fId + ",'userId':" + userId + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("Garage List Emailed!");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error :(");
        }
    });
    $('#emailGarageList').text('Email Garage List...');
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `$('#emailGarageList').text('Email Garage List...');` inside $.ajax call back function. $.ajax is an async call and your text below is updated right away before completing the ajax call.

```
function EmailGarageList(fId) {
    $('#emailGarageList').text('Please wait...');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/EmailGarageList",
        data: "{'fId':" + fId + ",'userId':" + userId + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("Garage List Emailed!");
            $('#emailGarageList').text('Email Garage List...');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error :(");
        }
    });    
};
```

Comment: i think the OP wants to display the `'Email Garage List...'` until the ajax call completes.

Comment: Even though idrumgods answer was correct also, I marked this one as accepted because it explained more clearly why my problem occurred (by mentioning the ajax call was async).

Answer (score 4):

put the `$('#emailGarageList').text('Email Garage List...');` inside your success function. Otherwise it changes, then changes right back.

Comment: i think the OP wants to display the `'Email Garage List...'` until the ajax call completes.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that jQuery Mobile (which I assume you are using), is modifying the DOM sso your selector cannot find $('#emailGarageList') the way you think it is.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about jquery mobile :) I was using normal jQuery.

Comment: I assumed based on your screenshot that you were including jQuery mobile because it looks identical to a jQuery mobile application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [beforeSend callback](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
    // other stuff ...
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('#emailGarageList').text('Please wait...');
    }
});
```